# Searching starting-method, if Android starts my proc

Tags: android

I have created an app with a service running as a background-thread of my app.
From time to time Andrdoid kills some apps, due to low memory.
One of these apps, which has been killed, was my application:

> > 07-29 14:48:35.140 I/ActivityManager(  145): Process test.myApp (pid 4847) has died.
> >
> > 07-29 14:48:35.140 W/ActivityManager(  145): Scheduling restart of crashed service test.myApp/.hilfsklassen.AutoSyncService in 19600ms
> >
> > 07-29 14:48:35.140 I/WindowManager(  145): WIN DEATH: Window{4071e300 test.myApp/test.myApp.Login paused=false}
> >
> > 07-29 14:48:35.150 I/WindowManager(  145): WIN DEATH: Window{407def28 test.myApp/test.myApp.Startseite paused=false}

Android started my app some seconds later:

> > 07-29 14:48:54.750 I/ActivityManager(  145): Start proc test.myApp for service test.myApp/.hilfsklassen.AutoSyncService: pid=7299 uid=10057 gids={3003}

But there is one problem:
My Service needs some data from test.myApp for running.
So I have know **what method of my start-activity will be called, if Android starts my app??**
I have tried onResume(), but this only works, if my app has the focuse (Foreground). If Android starts my app, it runs in the Background. So I thought it must be onRestart(), but this method was not be called. 
I have to start my service within this method in order to set some variables which are needed for running the service!

Chris

Answer (score 1):

The Android Runtime will kill background services without warning when memory becomes low. It will be restarted later if the onStartComand() method of the service returns `START_STICKY` or [START_FLAG_REDELIVERY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_FLAG_REDELIVERY). In the latter case the original intent to start the service is redelivered together with all extra data. The activity will only be started when the user launches it manually.

Another way would be to store your data somewhere (e.g. in `sharedPreferences`) and retrieve that data within the service. This way the service becomes independent of the activity. Hope that helps.